# XSLT document($variable) loading file from different server

Tags: xml, xslt, subdomain

I have a very strange problem going on with an XML document() call.

My code is very simple, but the results are very odd. I created a series of variables to describe the path to a particular file. Then I used document($varname) to bring in the file. It works, but brings in the file from one of our subdomains instead of the one I want.

Here's the code:

```
<xsl:variable name="serverSecure" >https://www.mywebsite.com</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="dirCorrected"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($dir, '\', '/'))" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="form" ><xsl:value-of select="$serverSecure" /><xsl:value-of select="$dirCorrected" />html/<xsl:value-of select="/page/@name" />.html</xsl:variable>
```

When the page loads, it doesn't bring up the file located at https://www.mywebsite.com/somedir/form/html/, it shows the page from https://**wwwtest**.mywebsite.com/somedir/form/html/.

This server was operating as a test server before we switched it to live, but we changed the configuration everywhere. I can't find anything that would point it to the test domain anymore.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I was told that I did not have a document() function in the original post, sorry about that. It is called later in the XSL:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document($form)"/>
```

To test it, I called the value-of for the $form variable:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$form" />
```

The output is what I expect, it shows the path that correctly leads to the www server. But the HTML file actually displayed is the one from the wwwtest subdomain server.

Comment: I don't see a document() function at all there. But I am not entirely sure what you are asking - if the document() function is bringing up the wrong page, print out the value of the address you are giving it, regardless of how you make it

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to load via `document()`?

Comment: We are trying to load https://www.mywebsite.com/somedir/form/html/somefile.html. The value-of $form comes back as that exact result, but the actual file output displayed by document($form) is the content on wwwtest.mywebsite.com.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all one can say for sure is that the problem isn't in the bit of code that you showed us. Something somewhere is intercepting the request and redirecting it. Tracking the problem down will be an incremental process of elimination - and the first thing I would do would be to try and reproduce the problem without involving any XSLT code: what happens when you use the same URI in the browser, or from curl?